# Best way to pass button selector from cell to View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have implemented a custom implementation of Swipeable cell. Partly based on this :- https://github.com/mbigatti/BMXSwipableCell

When the basementView is setup (this is the view which holds the buttons underneth the cell content view) we add two buttons like so:

```
    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.925 green:0.941 blue:0.945 alpha:1.000];
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(x + cellHeight, 0, cellHeight, cellHeight);
    [deleteButton setTitle: @"Test" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget: self
                     action: @selector(userPressedCallBasementButton:)
           forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

NOTE: This is called from a configureCell method, where the data model is passed to the tableviewcell subclass to configure that cell. The cell only has properties which are IBOutlets.

The method userPressedCallBasementButton is currently implemented in the cell subclass, as the target is self. However, the data that I need is on the View controller, i.e. the table data array.

Question: How can I have a target of the view controller for this button and have the method on the view controller? Further more, how would I get the specific cell reference/indexPath to be used in the view controller method too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Ignore undeclared selector warnings as this method is implemented in the VC
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
[moreButton addTarget:nil action: @selector(userPressedShareBasementButton:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

I found that setting `addTarget:nil` simply passes the method call up the chain, so implementing this method only on the View controller means it gets called as expected.

Answer (score 2):

First off, for the `indexPath` of the button, I've always subclassed `UIButton` and given it an `indexPath` property that can be set to the button when creating the cell.

**IndexedButton.h**

```
@interface IndexedButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@end
```

**SomeTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // create your cell...
    cell.deleteButton.indexPath = indexPath;
    // ...
    return cell;
}
```

As for notifying your main view controller, if you can't have the `indexedButton` send the action directly to you view, you can either fire off an `NSNotification` or set up a delegate protocol, whichever is your preference. The delegate/notification would send the aforementioned `indexPath` to tell your main view which button was pressed.

---

Delegate setup:

**CustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomCellDelegate;

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
// whatever else you have in your header goes here
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
// other delegate methods go here for other buttons that need to notify main view
- (void)callBasementButtonTapped:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
//...
- (void)userPressedCallBasementButton:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = ((IndexedButton *)sender).indexPath;
    id<CustomCellDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callBasementButtonTapped:)])
    {
        [strongDelegate callBasementButtonTapped:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, back in **SomeTableViewController.m**

```
@interface SomeTableViewController () <CustomCellDelegate>

//...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // create your cell...
    cell.deleteButton.indexPath = indexPath;
    cell.delegate = self;
    // ...
    return cell;
}

//...

- (void)callBasementButtonTapped:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do whatever you need to do here, and you have the index path
}
```

Comment: Ok, how do I create a delegate for this? So that the view controller is called for the button method? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but as I setup the cell in the cell custom class in a `configureCell` method the sender is the button. Therefore it does not have an indexPath like you have in `userPressedCallBasementButton...` does it?

Comment: Is there any need for this with my implementation as suggested in below answer too? Thanks

Comment: Combined with the subclassed button in the first part of the question, you have an index path.

Comment: I just did some research about the responder chain and it looks like it should work as long as you only declare the method in your table view controller and not in your custom cell class. I'd still suggest subclassing your button so that you can attach an `NSIndexPath` to the sender.